# How to change SharePoint 2010 User Interface Language on user level programaticly based on a locale id (LCID)

Tags: sharepoint

I have a issue with my current project. I am struggeling with how to change the User Interface Language for SharePoint 2010 programaticly based on a LCID. Does somone have any clues on how  to do this?
I have tried the following:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(1033);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;`
```

When do it this way nothing changes.

**Edit:**

I have solved my problem. It seems SharePoint 2010 have a javascript function it uses to change a user's ui language. I ended up doing this:

```
private void SetDisplayLanguage(uint lcid)
{
    string script = "<script language='javascript'>OnSelectionChange('" + lcid + "')</script>";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Register", script);
}
```

The OnSelectionChange method is a standard SharePoint 2010 method for changing ui language and works out of the box. The only thing you have to do is to pass a lcid to the function. I then call SetDisplayLanguage(your lcid) when i need to change ui language.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this post, that describes approach for setting lcid cookie will be helpful

http://www.n8d.at/blog/sharepoint-2010/change-language-of-ui-using-custom-control/